# Place two texts independently of each other

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to append two texts. I want them independent of eachother as currently they interfere with eachother and as such I cant accurately set their 'x' and 'y' values. I append a 'foreignObject' which they are both within, as well as some classes. If i append one with 'y', 0.. it works fine etc. The two of them dont work together! Perhaps it's because they are within the same classes, unfortunately I am fairly new so I'm not sure. My expected result is that both texts are anchored to the centre node (see the filter for selecting the centre one) but can be placed without affecting eachother

[image]

my code:

```
addOrgNameText() {
const length = this.nodes[0] && this.nodes[0].name ? this.nodes[0].name.length : 0;
const expr = length > 50 || this.mainNodeType !== NODE_IMAGE_TYPE.title;
let titleClass = `Engagement-OrganizationTitle--${expr ? 'Small' : 'Big'}`;
titleClass += this.mainNodeType !== NODE_IMAGE_TYPE.title ? ' Engagement-OrganizationTitle--Uncentered' : '';
this.group
  .selectAll('foreignObject')
  .data(this.nodes, node => node)
  .enter()
  .filter(node => !node.parent)
  .append('foreignObject')
  .attr('class', 'Engagement-GraphNodeLabel')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, 0)`)
  .attr('width', node => node.depth === 0 ? node.nodeRadius * 2 : this.labelWidth)
  .attr('height', node => this.nodeHeight(node))
  .style('opacity', node => node.visible ? 1 : 0)
  .style('visibility', node => node.visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden')
  .append('xhtml:div')
  .classed('Engagement-GraphNodeLabelText', node => node.depth !== 0)
  .classed('Engagement-GraphOrganizationTitle ' + titleClass, node => node.depth === 0)
  .html(node => {
    return `<p>1ST TEXT</p>`;
  })
  .selectAll('foreignObject')
  .data(this.nodes, node => node)
  .enter()
  .filter(node => !node.parent)
  .append('foreignObject')
  .attr('class', 'Engagement-GraphNodeLabel')
  .attr('x', 50)
  .attr('y', 100)
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, 0)`)
  .attr('width', node => node.depth === 0 ? node.nodeRadius * 2 : this.labelWidth)
  .attr('height', node => this.nodeHeight(node))
  .style('opacity', node => node.visible ? 1 : 0)
  .style('visibility', node => node.visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden')
  .append('xhtml:div')
  .classed('Engagement-GraphNodeLabelText', node => node.depth !== 0)
  .classed('Engagement-GraphOrganizationTitle ' + titleClass, node => node.depth === 0)
  .html(node => {
    return `<p>2ND TEXT</p>`;
  });
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, i have been stuck on this for awhile now.

Comment: text cannot be a child element of a circle.

Comment: What would I have to do?

Comment: Make the text element a sibling rather than a child.

Comment: I think i've sort of figured how to do it, because the text in the centre is a 'sibling; as I think you suggest, I will add the updated code and maybe it will be clearer